# sendto() return error code ENETDOWN

Tags: networking, packet

I met very strange situation.

In my program, the `sendto()` function returns error code `ENETDOWN(Network is down)` even though network is up and ping tryout success.

It's happened only when **UDP** stream connects to other network through several gateways. It's not always and happened sometimes. 
If i run same code under same sub network, there is no error like `ENETDOWN`.

So, i trace `sendto()` function to *Kernel area*. 
The `neigh_hh_output()` function in `ip_finish_output2()` of `iop_output.c` calls  `hh->hh_output()` and it returns `ENETDOWN` error code.

Under normal operation, `hh->hh_output()` function is assigned to `dev_queue_xmit()` of `dev.c` and packet's sent to network.

When issue was happened, it seems assigned to `neigh_blackhole()` function in `neigh_destroy()` of `neighbour.c`. The `neigh_blackhole()` returns `-ENETDOWN` code.

But, i don't know when the `neigh_destroy()` is called and why that function is called.

I'm struggling with this problem for several weeks.

Answer (score 1):

My test machine is placed like below description.
Test machine --- gateway(1.1.1.1) --- firewall(1.1.1.2) --- network ---- Destination.

First time, UDP connection establish between my test machine and Destination and gateway address of my test machine is 1.1.1.1.
Traffic has no problem between test machine destination. After some time or right after, suddenly, transmit traffic fail with "Network is Down" error(Error number 100, ENETDOWN).
At this time, if i tryout ping to destination in my test machine, ping response OK.
When i capture packet front of my  test machine, ICMP redirect message comes from gateway(1.1.1.1).  Its information is "Redirect for Host" and New gate address is "1.1.1.2".
When my test machine's OS(Linux 3.0.35) received ICMP redirect message, it changes virtual function pointer of hh->hh_output() from ev_queue_xmit()  to neigh_blackhole(). Eventually, neigh_blackhole() return -ENETDOWN code.

So, change gate address of my test machine to 1.1.1.2. After that, "Network is down" error is not happened again.

I think that it's strange operation. sendto() function  doesn't return ENETDOWN code as the man page. But, it's return ENETDOWN code. 
Anyway, if the sendto() function returns -ENETDOWN even though network interface is update, how to overcome this error?  Do i re-connect UDP stream?

I wonder this issue is bug of Linux kernel 3.0.35.

If i will know or find thing about this issue, i will update in here. 
Please reference my case if anyone has similar issue with me.

Answer (score 0):

It is claimed that a neighbor will be deleted for a variety of reasons including the host changed its layer 2 address while retaining its layer 3 address or is no longer reachable.  See [this](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/linux_net/0596002556/understandlni-CHP-27-SECT-6.html#understandlni-CHP-27-SECT-6).  It also can be deleted if the gateway for the neighbor sends an ICMP redirect and the processing of redirects is enabled in the kernel.

If the neighbor is in the process of being deleted, then the packet is dispatched to neigh_blackhole which unconditionally returns `-ENETDOWN`.  See the code [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/neighbour.c#L91).

The man page for `sendto()` would lead you to believe that you shouldn't get `-ENETDOWN` under such circumstances, but this appears to be incorrect.

I would try to get a network capture when this occurs and look for ICMP messages indicating your destination is not reachable or for a change in the MAC address for the destination (or possibly a duplicate IP address) via ARP packets or the MAC addresses on the arriving packets from the destination.

Comment: If the machine where my program is running receives ICMP redirect message, is neighbor able to remove?

Comment: I can see ICMP redirect message which has "redirect for host" code and new gateway address.

Comment: I haven't looked at the kernel code to see if an ICMP redirect would cause this, but it is certainly possible.  I would advise treating the -ENETDOWN error as something transient and retry, maybe with a delay and maybe also with a backoff.

Comment: I would also advise understanding why exactly you are getting a ICMP redirect for host.  It is not clear that you want your network learning routes by an ICMP redirect.  And it could be a security issue.  Good luck.

Comment: @shin2011 An ICMP redirect does lookup and release the neighbor if ICMP redirection is enabled in the kernel.  See [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/route.c?v=3.2#L1409).